# How to use settings for Vim Explorer?

Tags: vimrc

I tend to use `vim .` to explore my directories.

However, settings from `~/.vimrc` only seem to take effect for `vim FILENAME` rather than `vim DIR`.

For example, i have `set rnu` in my `~/.vimrc` file, but when i use `vim .` i do not see the relative line numbers. On the other hand, `vim FILE` will show the relative line numbers.

Does anyone know how i can configure settings to apply to the Vim Explorer as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as "Vim Explorer". You're probably using netrw-plugin (which also provides `:Explore` command).

If that's the case you can setup your options with `:h g:netrw_bufsettings`. For instance,

```
let g:netrw_bufsettings = 'noma nomod nobl nowrap ro nonu rnu'
```

Anyway, if some option "does not work" for specific window or buffer, that's because that window or buffer has its own local value of that option which happens to be different from the global default one.

Comment: I think you can also use the filetype mechanism for netrw

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Netrw can reset local settings. A horrible thing, IMO.